# Framework7 - PhotoBrowser onClose function

Tags: javascript, cordova, html-framework-7

I am using `framework7`in my mobile app and I want to [PhotoBrowser](http://framework7.io/docs/photo-browser.html) to display my images.

However, I want to detect when user close the PhotoBrowser so that I can process whatever is needed. In the documentation there is a `onClose(photobrowser)` callback function. But I am not sure how it works.

Based on the developer's coding conventions, it should be:

```
myPhotoBrowser.on('close', dosomefucntion());
```

but error:

> myPhotoBrowserPopupDark.on is not a function

I tried

```
onClose(myPhotoBrowser, dosomefucntion());
```

and nothing happen, not even error.

I check his other framework [SwiperSlider](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WIV_lrFh234), he seems to use

```
mySwiper.on('slideChangeStart', function () {
    console.log('slide change start 2');
});
```

to handle the callback function.

What seems to be the issue and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, Can you please share your code via http://jsfiddle.com so that we can help detect your error?

Answer (score 0):

what is `type` property of your `photoBrowser`? if you set your `photoBrowser` object `type` to "page" `onClose` event won't trigger.

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues/1243